# How to get a tweet with its full JSON in Twitter4j

Tags: json, twitter4j

I need to retrive a list of tweets, with many informations (easily retrievable from some Tweet.getX() methods) except for the tweet's entire JSON.

I can't figure out how to get the JSON of a tweet belonging from a QueryResult. Anyone can help me?

Comment: how is `TwitterObjectFactory.jsonStoreEnabled` used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the JSON of your tweets by setting `setJSONStoreEnabled(true);` on the `ConfigurationBuilder` object that you pass to your `TwitterFactory` constructor.

Here's a full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    Query query = new Query("lizardbill");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
        System.out.println(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
        String json = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(tweet);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bill! Saying "DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(tweet)" cause another query to Twitter API, right? It's not achievable throught some property of the retrieved tweet, is it? Thank, Andrea

Comment: @andreaxi Unfortunately, no, I don't think the JSON string is saved as a part of the Tweet object.

Comment: Well, I'll find other ways (maybe getting the JSON and then parse it to get the info I need: so just a query for the JSON, and a few of work to parse JSON). Thanks, Bill.

Comment: `DataObjectFactory` is now deprecated, you need to use `TwitterObjectFactory.jsonStoreEnabled`

Comment: What if I want to use stream API not search API, how to achieve this?

Comment: HAA. I knew it. I just wasted my time writing JSON using Jackson JSONGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bill answered the question but those who are still wondering about using `TwitterObjectFactory`, I believe it's done like this:

```
ResponseList<Status> userTimeline = // init twitter instance

userTimeline.forEach(x -> {
        String json = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(x);
        System.out.println(json);
    });
```